# bitnami /opt/bitnami/mysql/data increases in size by itself

Tags: mysql, linux, bitnami

how are you? I have been trying to solve this for a long time and I have not been able to, the case is like this.
I have an instance in amazon lightsail it was 1 GB RAM, 1 vCPU, 40 GB SSD
but due to space issues, upgrade to 2 GB RAM, 1 vCPU, 60 GB SSD

Yesterday it had only 20 GB occupied in the main storage:

[image: File System Overview 20 GB]

Today it is already occupying 40 GB:

[image: File System Overview 40 GB]

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo du -shx /\* | sort -h
```

until you get to this path

```
sudo du -shx /opt/bitnami/mysql/\* | sort -h
```

and discover that

```
/opt/bitnami/mysql/data
```

...weighs in at around 37GB:

[image: File System Overview Showing MySQL Data at 35 GB]

Does anyone know how I can see why it is doing that?

I still don't know how to stop it from filling up the storage

Comment: What's the largest file below .../data/?

Comment: it does not give me more results

Comment: `ls -lR /opt/bitnami/mysql/`